# How is App.OnSearchActivated different from App.OnActivated w/ActivationKind.Search?

Tags: windows-8, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml, activation

If you are implementing the Search Contract on a Windows Store App, then in your App.xaml.cs you override the `OnSearchActivated` method like this:

```
protected override void OnSearchActivated(SearchActivatedEventArgs args)
{
    (Window.Current.Content as Frame).Navigate(typeof(Contracts.Search), args.QueryText);
}
```

But if you are paying attention, then you can see that there is another override in the App class called `OnActivated` that has event arguments indicating a search activation, like this:

```
protected override void OnActivated(IActivatedEventArgs args)
{
    if (args.Kind == ActivationKind.Search)
    {
        (Window.Current.Content as Frame).Navigate(typeof(Contracts.Search), args.QueryText);
    }
}
```

When I implement one or the other the result seems to be the same. That begs the question: what is the difference between the two? **Are they really the same?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, they are the same.

The XAML team made a design decision to implement a generic `OnActivated` override as well as strongly typed overrides for the most common types of app activation. It is a best practice that, if there is a specific override, you use the specific override (like `OnSearchActivated`). But some advanced scenarios, like file or protocol activation, require `OnActivated`.

Note: in the `Page` pipeline, `OnActivated` fires first, the typed overrides follow. Since an app can only be activated by a single kind at a time, the order of execution doesn't matter.

Best of luck!